# Employment letter for H1B - can it have an electronic signature instead of an ink signature

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa, paperwork

I am an Indian citizen (with an Indian passport) working in Paris on a long stay French visa (valid until 28/Apr/2015). I have a PHD from a US university in 2013 and  a job offer (job starts 1/May/2015) from the same US university and qualified through the "cap exempt" H1B petition. My approved I-797 says that I can apply for H1B stamping at the Paris consulate in France.

The list of documents required for the interview are published [on the US embassy in France's website](http://france.usembassy.gov/niv/work.html) as:

- A valid passport
- DS-160 online application confirmation page
- One photograph taken within the last 6 months
- Original of Form I-797.  If the I-797 was approved more than two months prior to your visa interview, bring a letter from your employer confirming your continued employment.

The [supporting documents are mentioned](http://france.usembassy.gov/nivdocuments.html) as being the I-797 in "original or copy".

My employer however did mail me a physical copy of the letter of employment. Alas my name is printed incorrectly (one letter is incorrect: I suppose that renders the name incorrect).

Since the employment letter is not a required document since my I-797 was approved last week and NOT 2 months ago, should I go ahead with scheduling a visa appointment in the interest of time? (I have 2.5 more months left on my French visa and I would like to get my US visa before this expires.)

**Question:**

However, just to be on the safe side, can my employer send me a corrected employment letter via email with an *electronic signature* as against a physical letter with an *ink signature*?

I don't want further delays in shipping of letters to affect my visa interview date and figured that a letter through email attachment would be way quicker (instantaneous) than postal mail service (1 week wait at least).

Comment: Can't they scan the signed letter?

Comment: @littleadv I don't know. Can they? Does an "ink signature" imply authenticity as against a SCANNED ink signature? Is this a legal question?

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it. They should write a letter with letterhead and all, with a phone to call to for verification, and send it over to you. I would really be surprised if someone cared if it is scanned or hand-delivered in a brief case by James Bond flying on a special private plane flown by Eric Schmidt just to bring you the original signature.

Comment: @littleadv sigh. You are probably correct. US visas (and other visas) have needed some over-thinking now and then as I can't always judge the mood of the visa officer. Doubt JB would be able to either.

Comment: immihelp.com may be a better forum for this question

Answer (score 1):

An original needs to be just that, a document printed out and signed. In these circumstances, have the company correct, sign, and electronically send you the corrected version (identical expect for the spelling error). Take both with you, the original with the error and the corrected version.

Along with all your other supporting documents, with your name spelled accurately, it is unlikely that stamping would be delayed or refused.